# Add timestamp to API call JSON output

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

I need to add timestamp in key-value format on a JSON response. This is what I have right now:

```
  now = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(sep=" ", timespec="seconds")
    result = session.get(urljoin(baseurl, path), headers=headers, params=querystring, verify=False)
    jsonarray = result.json()
    json_object = json.dumps(jsonarray)
    #writing to outputfile
    with open("/opt/bamboo/logs/outputfile", "a") as outfile:
      outfile.write(now + json_object + "\n")
```

current output looks like this

```
2023-06-26 12:41:49{"account": "act_F-AC-1234", "contract": "ctr_F-1234"}
2023-06-26 12:42:49{"account": "act_F-AC-5678", "contract": "ctr_F-5678"}
```

my desired output should be

```
{"date_time": "2023-06-26 12:41:49", "account": "act_F-AC-1234", "contract": "ctr_F-1234"}
{"date_time": "2023-06-26 12:42:49", "account": "act_F-AC-5678", "contract": "ctr_F-5678"}
```

please note that the actual API call result (result.json) looks like below in proper format

```
{
  "account": "act_F-AC-1234",
  "contract": "ctr_F-1234",
  "rules": {
    "name": "default",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Route to origin",
        "children": [],
        "behaviors": [
          {
            "name": "origin",
            "options": {
              "originType": "CUSTOMER",
              "hostname": "elb.test.gateway.origin.com",
```

thanks in advance

Comment: It's just a normal Python dictionary.  Do `jsonarray['date_time'] = now` before you do the `json.dumps`.  Also, you can just do `json.dump( jsonarray, outfile )` and let it do the writing.  You don't have to convert to string first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to achieve my desired output

```
result = session.get(urljoin(baseurl, path), headers=headers, params=querystring, verify=False)
  ruletree = result.json()
  now = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  new_d = {"date_time": now, **ruletree}
  with open('/opt/bamboo/logs/outputfile', 'a') as outfile:
    json.dump(new_d, outfile)
    print(file=outfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling it "jsonarray", but it is neither JSON nor is it an array.  It is a simple Python dictionary.

```
    now = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(sep=" ", timespec="seconds")
    result = session.get(urljoin(baseurl, path), headers=headers, params=querystring, verify=False)
    jsonarray = result.json()
    jsonarray['date_time'] = now
    with open("/opt/bamboo-agents/akamai/logs/outputfile", "a") as outfile:
        json.dump( jsonarray, outfile )
```

HOWEVER, be aware that the result file is not valid JSON.  A JSON document is a single structure, not a set of separate structures.

Comment: Hi Tim, I have updated my post above with how the actual API call result looks like. I tried your code above and timestamp was added at the end `{"account": "act_F-AC-5678", "contract": "ctr_F-5678", "date_time": "2023-06-26 13:23:03"}` also, in terms of formatting, will it be better to append timestamp before the first key-value pair `{"date_time":"2023-06-26 12:41:49","account": "act_F-AC-1234", "contract": "ctr_F-1234"}`

Comment: The elements in a JSON object are unsorted.  The ordering makes no difference at all, and you shouldn't be worried about "formatting" in something designed for a computer to read.

Comment: I see. But purpose is to ingest the data into a logging app that's why timestamp should be at the beginning and each json result should be written per line hence the `"\n"` hoping you could help me achieve the desired output above, thanks

Comment: If your logging app reads JSON, then it DOES NOT CARE about the order of the entries.   That's in the spec.  And are you really telling me you don't know how to write a blank line to a file in Python?  `print(file=outfile)`.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your answers which helped me come up with a code to get my desired output. This is my very first python code.